# How to use ctags and vim to jump to java methods

Tags: vim, java, ctags

This *used* to work before I upgraded my Ubuntu system:

```
ctags *.java
vim -t fooFunc
```

Which would then take me to e.g. `Foo.fooFunc()`

But now, vim goes to the standard "tag not found" page.

I now have to do:

```
vim -t Foo.fooFunc()
```

For it to do the right thing.

More importantly, **^]** no longer works at all.

Looking at the generated **tags** file, I see entries like:

```
Foo.fooFunc Foo.java  /^    private void fooFunc() {$/
```

While the **tags** file generated by an older version of ctags would have looked like

```
fooFunc Foo.java  /^    private void fooFunc() {$/
```

so it looks like ctags is now broken.

Is there a way to revert to the old behavior? Or make vim respect the new format?

Comment: Just some guesses. Make  ctags is exuberant ctags. Check to see if you have a `~/.ctags` file. If you do  check to see what flags you have enabled by default.

Comment: Show us output of `ctags --version`

Comment: ctags (GNU Emacs 23.3)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed under the terms in ETAGS.README

Comment: Also, there is no ~/.ctags file

Answer (score 4):

I use [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) with the command

```
ctags --languages=java -R ./src
```

I was confused at first because a different version of ctags comes preinstalled on osx. Turns out I first had to replace it with universal-ctags

```
brew install --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Exuberant Ctags 5.8` and run the following script to generate a `tags` file for my java directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
# zero out any previously generated tags file
# an alternative way to achieve this is by `> tags`  
truncate --size 0 tags 
find . -name \*.java -exec ctags --append {} \;
```

I use `find` and `--append` because there are more than 1000 `.java` files in the directory.

No problems with `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0`.